How to show $(a_n z^n+a_{n+1} z^{n+1}\ldots)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ have closed orbit in any neighborhood of origin?
On the complex plane, consider the vector field
$$
(a_n z^n+a_{n+1} z^{n+1}\ldots)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\tag{1}
$$
where $a_i\in \mathbb C$ are constant, $n>1$, and
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\left( 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\right)
\tag{2}
$$
I want to know how to show the vector field have closed orbit in any neighborhood of origin ?  This problem is from the picture bottom which is from Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces (237- 262 of this).
What I try: I am a beginner of complex analysis, in fact, I have no idea about this problem. So, I try the cases $z^2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $z^3\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$. The results as pictures below. They do have closed orbit in any neighborhood of origin.

The orbits of $z^2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $z^3\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$.



The problem origin



You have reposted the identical question with the identical error in (1). You continue to misinterpret $az^p*\dots$. The $\dots$ represents higher order terms.

@TedShifrin  Thanks, I never realized $\dots$ represents higher order terms. Besides,  I did ask the same question, but I can't find it.  Did you tell me the answer in comment? Honestly, I didn't get it. And now  I fail to find that question, I can't keep thinking about it.  If you have time, could you explain it to me?  Thanks very much.

The result is true when $v(z)=z^p$ for $p\ge 2$. But we can make an analytic change of coordinates in a neighborhood of $0$ to turn $az^p+\dots$ into $z^p$.

Thank you. If I want more details, which book should I read?

Any complex analysis text should prove what I said. It’s very straightforward. Just choose a branch of the $p$th root in a neighborhood of $a\ne 0$, and write $az^p + \dots = z^p(a+g(z))$, and then take $w=z\root p\of{a+g(z)}$ on a disk on which $|g(z)|<|a|$.

I'm so stupid. Let me think about  why $v(z)=z^p (p>2)$ is true. Thanks again.
